# Sitecore Video Library Fancybox Youtube Integration

Tags: video, sitecore

We are currently using the sitecore CMS tool and we are using fancybox to play our videos. Currently our users upload OGV and MP4 Videos for playback that popup in a player. I am trying to give them the option to embed a youtube video instead if they do not have the OGV or MP4 videos.

The video item is passed in by an ItemID that is created by the user where they can attach a OGV, MP4 and a video thumbnail.

I have tried numerous things but can't get it to work.

First I created a singletext field in Sitecore CMS for the Youtube Video address.

Next we have a VideoPlayer.ASPX.CS and VideoPlayer.ASPX that I tried adding this line of code to, but it didn't work:
    VideoYouTube = "http://" + Request.Url.Host +     SitecoreUtility.GetVideoMediaUrl(videoItem, "VideoYoutube")

I was wondering if I could get some help so that I can get this to work. For the VideoPlayer.ASPX.CS here is the code that is working so far:

```
    public partial class videoPlayer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string VideoImage { get; set; }
        public string VideoMp4 { get; set; }
        public string VideoOgv { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string itemID = WebUtil.GetQueryString("itemID", "");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemID))
            {
                Item videoItem = SitecoreUtility.Db.GetItem(new ID(new Guid(itemID)));

                VideoImage = "http://" + Request.Url.Host +     SitecoreUtility.GetMediaUrl(videoItem, "VideoImage");
                VideoMp4 = "http://" + Request.Url.Host +     SitecoreUtility.GetVideoMediaUrl(videoItem, "Video_MP4");
                VideoOgv = "http://" + Request.Url.Host +     SitecoreUtility.GetVideoMediaUrl(videoItem, "Video_OGV");
            }
        }
    }
```

For the VideoPlayer.ASPX file here is the working code I have so far:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <!--[if !IE]><!--> 
        <link href="/css/video_popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/js/video.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]--> 
    <!--[if gte IE 9]> 
        <link href="/css/video_popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/js/video.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <video id="videoContainer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="480" height="360"
  poster="<%= VideoImage %>"
  data-setup="{}">
    <source src="<%= VideoMp4 %>" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="<%= VideoOgv %>" type='video/ogg' />

    <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="480" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["<%= VideoImage %>", {"url": "<%= VideoMp4 %>","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />

        <img src="<%= VideoImage %>" width="480" height="360" alt="Poster Image" title="No video playback capabilities." />
    </object>
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have it shouldn't be too hard to get a youtube video URL out and to put it in fancy box.

In the page code as you already have the sitecore item you just need to retrieve the item URL from the correct field. So in sitecore for your setup and field name this would be

```
string Video_YouTube = videoItem.Fields["VideoYoutube"].Value;
```

This can then be placed in an anchor tag on the aspx page as described in

http://webdesignandsuch.com/fancybox-youtube-videos/

As long as the user puts the full address of the youtube video in this should be ok.

Alternatively there is a  youtube integration module for sitecore that you could install which lets you pull down videos from a youtube account and then a user can configure a field to pull these through and let a user select one.

http://trac.sitecore.net/YouTubeIntegration

Comment: I am kinda confused here. I added that code, but I am still having issues.

Comment: I have this so far, but nothing is working:
      
     Video_YouTube = "http://" + Request.Url.Host + SitecoreUtility.GetVideoMediaUrl(videoItem, "VideoYoutube");

public string Video_YouTube { get; set; }

Comment: You should not need to get the VideoMediaUrl for the youtube video item as its not a sitecore media item if I understand your first post correctly and the 'VideoYouTube' is just a youtube link. You will also not need to add your host url to it as it would just make an invalid link. Just having Video_YouTube = videoItem.Fields["VideoYoutube"].Value; would get you your link. You can then take this link and either embed it or use it in fancy box as needed.

Comment: Can you give me a hardcore example with the code that I have given? Let me know. Thanks

Comment: This is the code I have so far and nothing is working.
string Video_YouTube { get; set; }

 Video_YouTube = videoItem.Fields["VideoYoutube"].Value;

<param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["<%= VideoImage %>", {"url": "<%= Video_YouTube %>","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />